# How to use get_serving_url in appengine?

Tags: image, google-app-engine, image-processing

The following is my main.py so far.

```py
import cgi
import datetime
import logging

from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
from google.appengine.api import images

logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


class Greeting(db.Model):
    author = db.UserProperty()
    content = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)
    imageblob = blobstore.BlobReferebceProperty()
    date = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write('<html><body>')
        query_str = "SELECT * FROM Greeting ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 10"
        greetings = db.GqlQuery (query_str)

        for greeting in greetings:
            if greeting.author:
                self.response.out.write('<b>%s</b> wrote:' % greeting.author.nickname())
            else:
                self.response.out.write('An anonymous person wrote:')
            self.response.out.write("<div><img src='img?img_id=%s'></img>" %
                                greeting.key())
            self.response.out.write(' %s</div>' %
                              cgi.escape(greeting.content))

        self.response.out.write("""
          <form action="/sign" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            <div><label>Message:</label></div>
            <div><textarea name="content" rows="3" cols="60"></textarea></div>
            <div><label>Avatar:</label></div>
            <div><input type="file" name="img"/></div>
            <div><input type="submit" value="Sign Guestbook"></div>
          </form>
        </body>
        </html>""")

class Image (webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        greeting = db.get(self.request.get("img_id"))
        if greeting.avatar:
            self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = "image/png"
            self.response.out.write(greeting.avatar)
        else:
            self.response.out.write("No image")

class Guestbook(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        greeting = Greeting()
        if users.get_current_user():
            greeting.author = users.get_current_user()
        greeting.content = self.request.get("content")
        avatar = get_serving_url(self.request.get("img"), size=None, crop=False)
        #avatar = images.crop(self.request.get("img"), 0.0, 0.0,1.0,0.5)
        greeting.avatar = db.Blob(avatar)
        greeting.put()
        self.redirect('/')


application = webapp.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainPage),
    ('/img', Image),
    ('/sign', Guestbook)
], debug=True)


def main():
    run_wsgi_app(application)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Please tell us what the problem is and why you're trying to accomplish - it'll get you a quicker and better answer.

Comment: @Sudhir I basically want all my images to render at same width and height. When I use the resize function of image api it only satisfies one property ( either width or height). Since get_serving_url is more dynamic than images api I want to use that.

Answer (score 2):

Like it says in [the docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/functions.html):

> Returns a URL that serves the image.
>   This URL format allows dynamic
>   resizing and cropping, so you don't
>   need to store different image sizes on
>   the server. Images are served with low
>   latency from a highly optimized,
>   cookieless infrastructure.

In your code you seem to be using `get_serving_url()` to construct a `Blob`. This will not work, since `get_serving_url()` returns a URL, not the image data.

You also seem to be confusing a [`blobstore.BlobReferenceProperty`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#BlobReferenceProperty) and a [`db.BlobProperty`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#BlobProperty) -- a `BlobReferenceProperty` references an object uploaded and stored in the [blobstore](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/) while a `BlobProperty` stores blob data directly in the datastore.

A better solution to your problem would be to store the image you get in the request (as a `BlobProperty`) in your model, then serve it at different sizes using `get_serving_url()`.

Alternatively, if you expect to be storing large images, store the images in the blobstore and use the `BlobReferenceProperty` -- either way, you should only be using `get_serving_url()` to *serve* the image, not in storing it.