# blobkey from blobstore google apps engine python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore

How do you return the blob key from a blob store? and subsequently return the image URL?

Example code:

```
class Next(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        userTable_name=self.request.get('userTable_name')

        data  = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * "
                                "FROM userTable "
                                "WHERE ANCESTOR IS :1 "
                                "ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 10",
                                userTable_key(userTable_name))

        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'


        for user in data:
            blobURL = get_serving_url(user.imageblob.key(), size=None, crop=False)
            self.response.out.write(blobURL)
```

I'm using a GqlQuery to return a set of Blobs (i.e. user.imageblob) and for each blob i need to determine the BlobKey. From what I can tell, "user.imageblob.key()" does not return the blobkey...?

Comment: it returns: "ValidateString if len(value.encode('utf-8')) > max_len:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)"

Comment: `user.imageblob.key()` _is_ the blobkey, albeit an inefficient way of getting it. Please include the actual code you tried, and the complete stacktrace, in your question.

Comment: Perhaps this answered question will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887535/need-help-processing-upload-form-with-google-app-engine-blobstore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out! As it turns out, I was confusing "adding an image to the datastore as a blob" vs vs adding an image to the blobstore.

> a BlobReferenceProperty references an object uploaded and stored in
>   the blobstore while a BlobProperty stores blob data directly in the
>   datastore. see: [How to use get_serving_url in appengine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3864045/how-to-use-get-serving-url-in-appengine).

Hence, `get_serving_url()` and `user.imageblob.key()` were incorrectly pointing to the datastore as opposed to the blobstore.

For examples of adding images to the blobstore see: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview.html